# importing specific class not working

Tags: python

i've created a file with the name `enviroment.py` which contain a `Profile` class however when i in another file try to import the file like `import testProject.enviroment import Profile` i get below error

```
yaml_helper.py", line 11, in read_yaml
     with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
```

however i'm not sure why it gives this error since the Profile hasnt even been initialized. all i've done is imported it?

**enviroment.py**

```
class Profile(object):
    def __init__(self, profile):

        self.profile = yaml_helper.read_yaml(project.default_profiles_dir, profile)

        self.run_enviroment()

    def get(self, key):
        return self.profile.get(key)

    def run_enviroment(self):
        return common.validate(connectors.exasol_credentials, self.profile)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not an import error. That's an error when the program is trying to open a file. The problem is where you call `yaml_helper.read_yaml`.

Are you passing in the correct parameters? for example, in that call, you are passing in `project.default_profies_dir` What is `project`? I don't see it defined. That could be your problem.

Comment: i'm only calling `yaml_helper.read_yaml` in Profile and im not even initializing `Profile` only importing

Comment: And your getting that error??? That's interesting. So you're not calling `Profile()` anywhere??? Then, I don't know.

Comment: @PeterPik Does accepting the answer mean that this was the problem?